# Can´t send notification with Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I´m trying to send a notification to all the users in each list of "Users" of each "Device" when a change is done under "Notifications". I know that the app is working because when I do manually in the browser I receive the notification.

I have also this error in the registry of de cloud function:

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
at exports.notifications.functions.database.ref.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:88:5)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

DB:

[image]

Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');  // this is the Admin SDK, not firebase-functions

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.database()
const ms = admin.messaging()

exports.notifications = functions.database.ref('Notifications/{id}').onUpdate(async(evt) =>{


const payload = {
    notification:{
        title   : 'Alarma se activó tu cerca',
        body    : 'Se activó tu cerca, revisala',
        badge   : '1',
        sound   :'defaul'   
    }
};

//Get Notification Device ID
const notySnap = await db.ref('Notification/').once('value');

var devicee = notySnap.notty;
var dev = JSON.stringify(devicee);



//Get number of users that the device had
const usersSnap = await db.ref('Devices/'+ dev + '/Users').once('value')
const nUsers = usersSnap.nUsers;
var Nusers = JSON.stringify(nUsers);
var nNUsers = parseInt(Nusers);



//Send notification to the number of users that exist
if (Nusers !== null){
    for(i = 0; 1 <=nNUsers; i++){
        if(i === 1){
            const userToSendP1 = usersSnap.user1;
            var userToSend1 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP1);
            Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 1");

        }else if(i === 2){
            const userToSendP2 = usersSnap.user2;
            var userToSend2 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP2);
            Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 2");

        }else if(i === 2){
            const userToSendP3 = usersSnap.user3;
            var userToSend3 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP3);
            Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 3");

        }else if(i === 2){
                const userToSendP4 = usersSnap.user4;
                var userToSend4 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP4);
                Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 4");

            }
        }
    }
  return response.send("Sended Notification").status(200);
})
```

Comment: does the `Console` is working?

Comment: I check it and no. this is the error of FB:
ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at exports.notifications.functions.database.ref.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:11:5)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Its lowercase console.

Comment: Yes you ere right but I still have some errors.